# Obtener el stack trace en Java sin imprimirlo

Tags: java

¿Cómo puedo obtener el stack trace en una posición del código cuando no se generó una excepción?

Vengo utilizando

```
try
{
  // código
}
catch (IOException e)
{
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

o incluso

```
e.getMessage()
```

dentro de una excepción, pero me interesa saber si hay alguna forma de obtener el stack trace en una parte específica del código, para poder modificarlo como texto, sin que se haya generado una excepción. Por ejemplo, para mostrar sólo el método actual y la línea. ¿Existe algún método que me lo devuelva?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes ejecutar [`Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getStackTrace--), lo que te devolverá un arreglo de [`StackTraceElement`s](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StackTraceElement.html) que puedes leer y manipular como desees.

Ejemplo:

```
StackTraceElement[] stackTraceElements = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
for (StackTraceElement ste : stackTraceElements) {
    System.out.printf("%s.%s(%s:%s)%n",
            ste.getClassName(),
            ste.getMethodName(),
            ste.getFileName(),
            ste.getLineNumber());
}
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://rextester.com/RMIL86266)</kbd>

Comment: Excelente, los métodos de StackTraceElement tienen todo lo que buscaba... probando

Comment: Exactamente lo que buscaba